# Windows CMD interpret code following alias

Tags: windows, batch-file, svn, cmd, alias

Is it possible to get windows process some code after an alias in the cmd? Basically I want to do sth. like this:

```
doskey mysvn = D:\portableSVN\bin\svn.exe --config-dir D:\portableSVN\config
mysvn up
mysvn ci -m "message"
```

This does not work, after interpreting `mysvn` it just stops and I get:

```
Subcommand argument required
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

Currently, I modify the `PATH`for the session and use the standard config folder, but I would rather not have my credentials and proxy settings on every pc I use my portable svn on. Of course I can delete them afterwards, but still they are recoverable.

If necessary, it is also possible to execute batch files as long as they don't need admin rights.

Comment: Aliases are evaluated in the console (conhost.exe) long before a client process such as cmd.exe reads the resulting input text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
doskey mysvn=D:\portableSVN\bin\svn.exe --config-dir D:\portableSVN\config $*
```

See `doskey /?` for more information

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. In case anyone is looking for an alternative: I also found `SET %mysvn%=D:\portableSVN\bin\svn.exe --config-dir D:\portableSVN\config` working, but always typing the `%` when calling the variable is somewhat annoying.